# How to create a navigation property with same primary key as parent table?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Two tables:

```
Orders [Key: OrderId]
OrderStats [Key: OrderId]
```

**Each order row has either zero or one rows in OrderStats. So orderId 1 has a row in OrderStats with primary key OrderId 1**

I want to create a navigation property on Orders, so I can do this...

```
Console.Writeline(myOrder.OrderStats.Profit)
```

How do I go about doing that in Entity Framework 6, code-first?

OrderStats is a table with some business intelligence information about each order, that is updated on a schedule. The table is separate for a number of practical reasons, irrelevant to this case.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the involved entity model/configuration and tell us what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify this relationship in `OnModelCreating` using:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(e => e.OrderStats).WithRequired();
```

Or as below if you also have a `Order` navigation property in `OrderStats`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasOptional(e => e.OrderStats).WithRequired(e => e.Order);
```

EF will keep the primary keys of both entities the same when performing database operations.